# What could be the cause of high leakage inductance on my custom flyback transformer?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, inductance, flyback

I've built a flyback transformer by hand for a circuit I am making and after shorting the secondary I have found my leakage inductance is very high. The primary inductance is around 2 mH, while the leakage inductance is at 1.3 mH and it is supposed to be at max only 60 uH. I have made the transformer twice now with the same result and I can't figure out what is going on.

Primary turns: 143

Secondary turns: 6 trifilar

As requested I am providing more detail. My primary inductance is calculated by:

$$ Lp = Vin^20.5*Duty*eff/(Po*fs)  $$

Vin = 135V, Duty=0.636, eff=0.72, Po = 10W, fs =137kHz

I need to have a target primary inductanced around 1900-2000 uH, and so I need to used a gapped core. The transformer construction given by PI designer is. Note there are 3 layers of tape between primary and secondary.

[image].

My Primary winding looks like this:
[image]

Shorted secondary to measure leakage:
[image]

Picture of core inside bobbin, there is a slight gap at the top which could potentially contribute:
[image]

The core material I am using is N27, core is gapped 0.17MM (recommended core gap from PI is 1.2 mm. [Here is the data sheet](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/e_20_10_6.pdf) The measurement was made on Proster 3M4070 LCR meter, accuracy should be off by roughly +/- 5 uH. The wires used for the core were not triple insulated, they are some wires I got off Amazon from [BNTechGO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HRKT1WQ)

Comment: You would have to show the details of your construction for anyone to have any chance at answering that.  A picture and a diagram of how the windings are wound with dimensions would be helpful.  It certainly sounds like incredibly high leakage so you may want to add exactly how you made the measurement.

Comment: Only 80% coupling? No core or capped.

Comment: I think that the volume of copper should be the same for both windings for best coupling (same # of Cu atoms).   If you are using the same guage for primary and secondary, then with 143 turns on the primary, then the secondary should have 6 turns of 24-filar winding. Or 6x3x8 alternatively 8 paralleled windings of 6 trifilar. But that's only if you are using same thickness wire throughout, I believe.

Comment: Also, flyback has to store energy, but if your gap is too big, you will have too much leakage. Also, some iron powder cores have distributed gaps, which is hidden because it represents how connected the powder is. May we please have more details? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: @JohnD I have updated the post with additional details.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I have updated the post with additional details.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously terrible except the solder joints on your shorting wire.  The gap between the bobbin and the core shouldn't have any impact.  Is your center leg ground to make the gap, or did you use spacers on all 3 legs? It's hard to tell from the diagram.

Comment: _”Secondary turns: 6 trifilar”_ From the look of it, it’s 3xsome wire guage in parallel, but it’s not _trifilar_. Try to wind it _bifilar_, usually with half of your primary turns, tape and margin tape, secondary turns, tape gain and then the remaining half of your primary turns.

Comment: @JohnD Centre leg was ground down by the manufacturer (TDK electronics). Solder joints are bad as I had to quickly re solder to take the photo.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure why your leakage is so high, but @winny's suggestion of interleaving the secondary and primary usually helps.  Transformer design is often an iterative process.

Answer (score 2):

the main cause of high leakage inductance is too much separation between the primary and secondary windings.  But please provide more details, such as a picture of the cross section, what's the core material, is it gapped, etc.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the post with additional details.